# Issue with angularjs filter sample

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn angularjs with the help of a book. I tried to execute one of the examples on how to use filters in AngularJS but its not giving desired results. I am not sure what I am missing and what is wrong with the code.

Below is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Listing 4-4</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myFilterDemo($scope){
            var someData = {
                    name: 'ashwini',
                    address: 'noida',
                    dateJoined: new Date(2015, 2, 14),
                    consumption:4567.12358,
                    plan: 'Super Basic Plan'
                };
                $scope.data = someData;
            }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller ="myFilterDemo">
        <p> Consumption: {{data.consumption}}<br/>
        <p> Consumption: {{data.consumption | Number}}
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hello  Ashwine, welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask where is explained which kind of questions will attract answers. Starting with a title that reflects a specific problem:)

Comment: What error are you getting on browser console?Where are your ng-app?

Comment: I am not getting any error as such. But I am not getting the desired result in the browser. here is the out put which I am getting on the browser : Consumption: {{data.consumption}} Consumption: {{data.consumption | Number}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only getting an issue on the filter , the number filter is used as follows. `{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}`

There are other problems in your code.

check this plnkr code for a working version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        function myFilterDemo($scope){
            var someData = {
                name: 'ashwini',
                address: 'noida',
                dateJoined: new Date(2015, 2, 14),
                consumption:4567.12358,
                plan: 'Super Basic Plan'
                };
                $scope.data = someData;
            }
        app.controller("myFilterDemo",myFilterDemo)
    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller ="myFilterDemo">
    <p> Consumption: {{data.consumption}}<br/>
    <p> Consumption: {{data.consumption | number}}</p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/TjpZOiLWpga2DQiY5hpW?p=preview

Comment: I am not getting any error as such. But I am not getting the desired result in the browser. here is the out put which I am getting on the browser : Consumption: {{data.consumption}}
Consumption: {{data.consumption | Number}}

Comment: the error you get is correct. Look at the code i have posted, there are few differences from your code. You need to create an ng-app and add your controllers to it. If the answer helps, you need to accept it as answer then folks will answer to your questions most probably.

Comment: do u still have any issues with this problem?

Comment: Yeah! you are right Kathir. Thanks a lot. I did the changes suggested by you and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

ng-app arrtibute is missing add

<body ng-app="yourapp" ng-controller ="myFilterDemo">

You can also check to work on filters on w3 schools
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp

Comment: I tried by adding the ng-app attribute as well but still the same result.